# In eclipse plugin development, how can I change text foreground color for specific words

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, text-coloring

I am developing an eclipse plugin. And I want to change text foreground color for specific words and 
pass the compiler rules in eclipse java editor environment.
The specific words is like //Mytag or like #Mytag. I don't want to make a own editor. I want add this
new syntax coloring to original java editor.

I ever try use a customized SourceViewerConfiguration to add new syntax coloring to original java editor. But it is not work.

Who knows whether I can use SourceViewerConfiguration to add new syntax coloring to original java editor. If not, which kinds of method I can meet my needs.

It bother me long ago. Very thanks your valuable advice!